# Didn't append the first value in a list from a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to create DataFrame from a list using for loop. But only the last value is appended in the DataFrame. Need a solution for that. I am very new in this topic. just trying to solve a personal problem.

I can print the values what I need with this code provided below. But when I trying to append these value into a DataFrame this is only appending the last value from the List.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import selenium.common.exceptions
import time 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
catlink=['https://www.daraz.com.bd/small-kitchen-appliances/','https://www.daraz.com.bd/bedding-bath/']
for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
        i+=i
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
        for element in elements:
            print(driver.title)
            print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

````py
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import selenium.common.exceptions
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
catlink=['https://www.daraz.com.bd/small-kitchen-appliances/','https://www.daraz.com.bd/bedding-bath/']
for link in catlink:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0,8):
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
            time.sleep(4)
            i+=1
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div.c2xMr_ > div.ant-carousel > div > div.slick-list>* a")
            title=[]
            # hreflink=[]
            for element in elements:
                title.append({'title':driver.title,'link':element.get_attribute("href")})
                df=pd.DataFrame(title)

        except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException):
            NoBanner=list()
            NoBanner.append(driver.title) 
            continue ```

I tried this but now showing the expected result.
````

Comment: You can use pd.concat to combine dfs.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new data frame for each iteration of your `for element in elements` loop, and assigning it to the variable `df`, thus rewriting over the previous value of `df`.